# IM003 (160) Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 126: The specified module could not be found

Tags: ruby, odbc, dbi

Ive spent the last month searching off and on for a solution, unsuccessfully

I have an underlying driver called `Timberline Data` on what we have to use as a production windows machine. For years I was using this driver for pulling data from a database. Then one day a windows update was released, something broke and I re-installed the application which includes the dll.

Now I'm getting the following error

The same code runs on my developer machine that i have not ran a windows update on for fear it will break.

---

I have read online that other people have experienced the same system error `IM003 (160) ... 126` with other ODBC drivers, but it looks like they experience issues because a network path was incorrectly mapped. Mine is installed on the `C:\` drive...

here's what I know:

- it's a 32 bit dll
- i'm running 32 bit ruby
- OS is Windows 10 (64 bit)
- to avoid using ODBC directly, I build a connection string, which I have confirmed works successfully in other ways on the machine experiencing the issues. So I know the dll is not broken.
- the same ruby code runs on the developer machine, so there is no issue with syntax, the issue is something in windows or with the installation

```rb
>> filepath = '\\\\SAGE\\Mapped_Drive\\Company\\'
=> "\\\\SAGE\\Mapped_Drive\\CAE\\"
>> uri = driver_builder(filepath)
=> "DBI:ODBC:Driver={Timberline Data};dbq=\\\\SAGE\\Mapped_Drive\\Company\\;standardmode=1;SilentLogin=1;KeepFilesOpen=0;MaxColSupport=255;DatabaseType=1;UID=...;PWD=...;"  
>> DBI.connect(uri)
```

```sh
DBI::DatabaseError: IM003 (160) Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  126: The specified module could not be found. (Timberline Data, C:\Program Files (x86)\Timberline Office\Shared\tssimba.dll).
    C:/Ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/dbd-odbc-0.2.5/lib/dbd/odbc/driver.rb:36:in `rescue in connect'
    C:/Ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/dbd-odbc-0.2.5/lib/dbd/odbc/driver.rb:15:in `connect'
    C:/Ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi/handles/driver.rb:33:in `connect'
    C:/Ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:148:in `connect'
    (ripl):3:in `<main>'
```

both me and several other co workers are beside ourselves on where the issue is

Answer (score 0):

Open Power BI desktop and follow below steps:

[image: Power BI Desktop Application]

[image: Clear Cache]

After clearing cache log off and login machine/VM.

Comment: last year I ended up just burning the machine, using a fresh OS and ruby install and the problem was solved. wont ever know what the issue was